# Running programs on a Cisco device

Tags: cisco

I use paramiko from (www.paramiko.org) to automate logging into Cisco devices and then checking logs, interface stats, anything i want really.

When i log into a device i am into a Management VRF. I don't have internet access.

If i want to test something for a customer, i need to do something like

```
ping vrf CUSTOMER_A 8.8.8.8 source Vlan 250
```

What i would like to do is make use of python to do things like

> wget 
>   speedtest-cli from GitHub 
>   basically emulate being on the customers end device

However, so far i have been unable to get close.

Has any fellow networkers ever tried something like this ?

A

Comment: How exactly do you expect to run those applications on a Cisco device? Also, which model and OS are you using?

Comment: I have no idea how i going to get them to run? The IOS could change dependent on what device i am going to connect to

Comment: You can't. You're comparing a router to a linux box, which (at least for Cisco) isn't the case.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... i am no so sure, what about ssh tunneling

Comment: And how would that help? You still wouldn't be able to run that software *on* the Cisco device.

Comment: Cisco uses a proprietary OS, so you cannot emulate a customer's end device from a Cisco device. You must use Cisco commands. You could create TCL scripts to automate some things, but you will not be able to run external applications on IOS.

Comment: @TeunVink : Classic IOS is not but most modern Cisco OS are built on Linux: IOS-XE, NXOS, ASA OS (version 9)

Comment: I know, but the OP was asking about the generic case. You're right of course that specific models and software versions do support this.

Comment: possible duplicate here [Traffic generation from Cisco IOS device to prove WAN circuit](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/traffic-generation-from-cisco-ios-device-to-prove-wan-circuit)

Comment: BTW: You can run linux directly on many newer Cisco boxes.  See [Run your apps and tools natively on Cisco boxes](http://www.cisco.com/assets/global/DK/seminarer/pdfs/cisco_virtual_update_fog_computing_iox_update.pdf)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

On a Cisco Nexus device - depending on the model and the NXOS version it runs -  you can get access to a bash shell, a Linux container and/or a Python interpreter (with possibility to import pure python modules).

E.g. for NXOS 7.x on the nexus3000:

> **About Bash**
>
> In addition to the NX-OS CLI, Cisco Nexus 3000 Series
> devices support access to the Bourne-Again SHell (Bash). Bash
> interprets commands that you enter or commands that are read from a
> shell script. Using Bash enables access to the underlying Linux system
> on the device and to manage the system.

And

> **About the Guest Shell**
>
> In addition to the NX-OS CLI and Bash access on
> the underlying Linux environment, the Cisco Nexus 3000 Series devices
> support access to a decoupled execution space running within a Linux
> Container (LXC) called the “Guest Shell”.
>
> From within the Guest Shell the network-admin has the following
> capabilities:
>
> Access to the network over Linux network interfaces.
> Access to Cisco Nexus 3000 bootflash.
> Access to Cisco Nexus 3000 volatile tmpfs.
> Access to Cisco Nexus 3000 CLI.
> Access to Cisco NX-API REST.
> The ability to install and run python scripts.
> The ability to install and run 32-bit and 64-bit Linux applications

.

Source: [Cisco Nexus 3000 Series NX-OS Programmability Guide, Release 7.x](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/programmability/7_x/b_Cisco_Nexus_3000_Series_NX-OS_Programmability_Guide_7x.html)

Answer (score 1):

[TTCP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/asynchronous-connections/10340-ttcp.html) should suit your needs. The good news is that it's built into the OS so you don't need to download any scripts or applications on the router.

You can use it between two routers or even a router and a PC. Further to this, you have the choice of running TTCP, iperf, jperf, etc on the PC side.

Note though that TTCP on a router is process switched so it has the potential use 100% of the CPU's resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate those tasks with [Cisco's EEM](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/117596/cisco-eem-basic-overview-and-sample-configurations) using [ttcp](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/traffic-generation-from-cisco-ios-device-to-prove-wan-circuit) and have the results emailed to you - hourly, daily, weekly, whatever.  This might be easiest.

[You can also spin up a linux VM on many newer Cisco boxes.](http://www.cisco.com/assets/global/DK/seminarer/pdfs/cisco_virtual_update_fog_computing_iox_update.pdf)

If you'd rather do it from a remote machine, Python could certainly be used or even Microsoft `sendkeys` class.

[Python examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python).

[Sendkeys example here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx)